# Hibernate 6.2 - from ClassCastException: BasicValue cannot be cast to ToOne to DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin

I was getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I've read that there is a bug in Hibernate 6.2 regarding this issue, so I had to change the mapping of the entities in the application.

The entity was implemented as unidirectional, so the use of `mappedBy` was probably not correct. This is what I had:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
class Customer(
    @Id
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerPortfolioId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    var customerPortfolios: List<CustomerPortfolio> = mutableListOf()
)
```

What I changed it into:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
class Customer(
    @Id
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = “customerPortfolioId”)
    var customerPortfolios: List<CustomerPortfolio> = mutableListOf()
)
```

CustomerPortfolio is just a simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “customer_portfolio”)
data class CustomerPortfolio(
    @Id
    val id: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),

    val customerPortfolioId: UUID
)
```

The mentioned exception is gone, but right now I'm getting

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: null value in column "customer_portfolio_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (a338ef9f-6b9f-4741-b7b3-7fd1a4894db0, null).] [update customer_portfolio set customer_portfolio_id=null where customer_portfolio_id=?]; SQL [update update customer_portfolio set customer_portfolio_id=null where customer_portfolio_id=?]; constraint [customer_portfolio_id]
```

...and I have no clue where this `UPDATE` sql comes from. I don't have it in my code. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: can you add ddl table examples?